MUI DatePicker Popper not aligned when less screen space
I have developed a date picker using the MUI date picker - https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/. When I click on the component while the date picker is positioned at the top of the screen there calendar component is rendering fine. However, when I have the component at the bottom of the screen or in the middle, in the instance when there is less screen space and we click on the date picker the calendar is rendered at the top of the page, we have to scroll up and then scroll down for the calendar component to be aligned appropriately.
My Component:
<DatePicker
    value="Date"
    onChange={handleDateChange}
    slots={{
              openPickerIcon: () => <FilterCalendarIcon date={filters.date} />,
    }}
    slotProps={{
            field: { clearable: true, onClear: () => handleDateChange(null) },
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} className="table-filter-input" />}
    label={FILTER_DATE_LABEL}
    className="table-filter-datepicker"
/>

How can I resolve this issue or make sure the component renders at the bottom or top of the component based on the screen space instead of rendering out of focus.
I tried using the following solution as well:
PopperComponent={(props) => (
        <Popper 
          {...props} 
          placement={determinePlacement()} 
          modifiers={[
            {
              name: 'offset',
              options: {
                offset: [0, 10], // Adjust offset if necessary
              },
            },
          ]}
        />
      )}

However, the issue is still not resolved. I don't see this behaviourial issue in the framework either.
